# Why does my DAI limit buy not go through for USDC?

Tags: 0x

I am trying to purchase USDC using the DAI I have in Metamask but it will not fill my order.

I've given Matcha permission to access my DAI, I've paid the ETH required and now I'd like to just place a free limit order to purchase USDC.  I've set up the limit buy for the matching price on the ticker, it congratlates me for placing the order and the confetti comes out, but it never fills my USDC buy.

I've gone through many forums, Reddits and had a friend, who recommended Matcha for the free limit buys, troubleshoot it with me, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone please assist me?  I've attached a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The order looks too small.

Placing limit orders is free because they are published in an order book that anyone can execute when the price is convenient for them. But this entity that executes (takes) the transaction has to pay the regular gas fees. So your trade is probably too small, both on spread and amount, to justify someone else paying gas to execute the order